# Android Studio Emulator directory removed

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I've accidentally removed the **emulator** directory from the Android/SDK folder. I'm using the Linux operating system. Is there any way to only download the only **emulator** directory...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reinstall the emulator you need to:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click on Tools-> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools
3. Search "Android Emulator", click on the checkbox to install it and apply the changes